# How to understand what two declarations are different

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I just kind of don't understand the sentece " if the declaration sets of  S ( f , B i )  and  S ( f , C )  differ" in [[class.member.lookup]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.member.lookup#6.2) section,what are different declarations except  that their types are different,such as If two declarations are declared the same type but they are declared in different scopes respectively,then, Are these two declarations difference?For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  void func(int);  //#1
  {
      void func(int); //#2
  }
}
```

So,#1 and #2 are different declarations?they have the same type,just be declared in different scope.If they are difference,where's the quote in the Internation standard says this?

Comment: As an initial matter, you are looking at the section "Member name lookup", but your example doesn't involve any classes or their members. What is it supposed to demonstrate?

Comment: There's an example in the standard [right under](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.member.lookup#7) the section you cite, which shows the case of an ambiguous merge. Basically, it's the case where there are two base classes, and each one declares `func`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  I just  want to make the case more general,in other words,one declaration in class A's scope and the other in class B's scope,they all have the same name and the same type,but in different scope,Are these declarations difference?if it is ,where's the quote says that if two declarations are all the same name and types,but in different scopes,they would be different declarations?

Comment: They declare different names - one is `A::func`, the other is `B::func`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik <pedantic mode>`A::func` and `B::func` aren't names. Names there are `A`, `B`, and `func`. And 2 `func`s are [the same](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#def:name,same).<pedantic mode/>

Comment: @LanguageLawyer OK. They are declarations of different members - one is `A::func` and the other is `B::func`. The definition of `S(f,C)` says that it holds *"a set of members named `f`"*, not a set of names.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer However,the sentence does not say these names are the same ,they say these declarations need to be the same,so,my questions is,if two declarations have the same name and the same type but they were declared in different scope,Do these two declarations differ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  you mean that if they are different members (the same name,same function type ,but in different class),then they are different declarations ,right?

Comment: Per the standard, a thing called "declaration set" doesn't actually hold declarations. "The lookup set for `f` in `C`, called `S(f,C)`, consists of two component sets: the declaration set, a set of **members named `f`**..." (emphasis mine). Clearly, `A::func` and `B::func` are different members of `C`. The issue doesn't hinge on the question of when and whether two declarations differ.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you mean,in this section, the standard does not actually want to say these declarations are different instead these members are different,Right?

Comment: That's my reading.

Comment: @lgorTandetnik  ok,how do you think about this "if two declarations have the same name and the same type but they were declared in different scope,Do these two declarations differ? "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you quote is from [class.member.lookup] which only applies to looking up names in class scope (as covered by the first sentence of the section).

In your sample code there are no classes so this section does not apply.

That code would be covered by [basic.link]/9:

> Two names that are the same (Clause 6) and that are declared in different scopes shall denote the same variable, function, type, template or namespace if
>
> - both names have external linkage or else both names have internal linkage and are declared in the same translation unit; and
> - both names refer to members of the same namespace or to members, not by inheritance, of the same class; and
> - when both names denote functions, the parameter-type-lists of the functions are identical; and
> - when both names denote function templates, the signatures (17.5.6.1) are the same.

All of the bullets are satisfied: both of your `func` have external linkage, they're both members of the global namespace, and the functions have identical parameter type lists, and they're not function templates.

Comment: thanks.So,the declaration set in  [class.member.lookup] means set of members of class,Right?If one `func` in class `A` and the other in class `B`,even if the parameter-type-lists are the same,but they in different class,So they are different declarations.However another questions is ,in your cited quote,what's the same variable?It doesn't seem to interpret the same varible clearly.

Comment: For example 
````int main(){
  int a;
{
  double a;
}
}
````
The `a` in declaration `int a` is the same name as another `a` in declaration `double a`,all of the bullets you cited are statisfied.Howerver,obvisouly,they are not the same declaration,so how to interpret it by that quote you cited?

Comment: For the second question,because a varialbe name which was delcared in block scope  does not have linkage ,so the first bullet point in the quote is not satisfied,so they are different declarations

Comment: @jackX `int a;` does not have external or internal linkage so the first bullet is not satisfied

Comment: yes,it is ,I have clarified it in our comment,thanks.A wonderful answers.+50

Comment: if two function declarations that have the same name and types and they are declared in the same scope,Do these declaration violate the rules "that are declared in different scopes",so they wouldn't denote the same function?